# Animate the clip: rect property?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, clip

I want to animate the css property `clip: rect` with jQuery's `.animate()` but can't find if this is possible anywhere. Have tried:

`$(".img1").animate({
    clip: "rect(1px, 945px, 499px, 1px)"

    },300);`

without any luck. Does anyone know?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Anything is possible, but there probably are easier ways to do what you want without using `clip`, but if you use jQuery animate's [fx.step](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#step) function, you can animate anything, but you need to do some calculations to figure out values and stuff, but it goes something like this:

```
$(".img1").animate({
  fontSize: 100 //some unimportant CSS to animate so we get some values
},
{
  step: function(now, fx) { //now is the animated value from initial css value
      $(this).css('clip', 'rect(0px, '+now+'px, '+now+'px, 0px)')
  }
}, 10000);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gCGk2/)

Comment: Pity you have to abuse some innocent CSS property, but excellent solution indeed! Thank you

Comment: But how can I control the animation speed ? changing the duration value does not help.

Comment: Ähm, you don't need to animate a pseudo property. You can use an object to pass the arguments: `$({to:0}).animate({to:100}, {step: function(){} })`

Comment: @yckart- could you set up a Fiddle for that, would be interesting to see how that works ?

Comment: `$({ val: 0 }).animate({ val: 100 }, { step: function (now) { console.log(now); } });`

Answer (score 4):

Since this is a popular question and was the top of Google search results when I looked for this today, here is a jQuery plugin that works with the `clip:` property and `.animate()` natively.

Credit: http://zduck.com/2013/jquery-css-clip-animation-plugin/

```
/*
* jquery.animate.clip.js
*
* jQuery css clip animation support -- Joshua Poehls
* version 0.1.4

* forked from Jim Palmer's plugin http://www.overset.com/2008/08/07/jquery-css-clip-animation-plugin/
* idea spawned from jquery.color.js by John Resig
* Released under the MIT license.
*/
(function (jQuery) {

    function getStyle(elem, name) {
        return (elem.currentStyle && elem.currentStyle[name]) || elem.style[name];
    }

    function getClip(elem) {
        var cssClip = $(elem).css('clip') || '';

        if (!cssClip) {
            // Try to get the clip rect another way for IE8.
            // This is a workaround for jQuery's css('clip') returning undefined
            // when the clip is defined in an external stylesheet in IE8. -JPOEHLS
            var pieces = {
                top: getStyle(elem, 'clipTop'),
                right: getStyle(elem, 'clipRight'),
                bottom: getStyle(elem, 'clipBottom'),
                left: getStyle(elem, 'clipLeft')
            };

            if (pieces.top && pieces.right && pieces.bottom && pieces.left) {
                cssClip = 'rect(' + pieces.top + ' ' + pieces.right + ' ' + pieces.bottom + ' ' + pieces.left + ')';
            }
        }

        // Strip commas and return.
        return cssClip.replace(/,/g, ' ');
    }

    jQuery.fx.step.clip = function (fx) {
        if (fx.pos === 0) {
            var cRE = /rect\(([0-9\.]{1,})(px|em)[,]?\s+([0-9\.]{1,})(px|em)[,]?\s+([0-9\.]{1,})(px|em)[,]?\s+([0-9\.]{1,})(px|em)\)/;

            fx.start = cRE.exec(getClip(fx.elem));
            if (typeof fx.end === 'string') {
                fx.end = cRE.exec(fx.end.replace(/,/g, ' '));
            }
        }
        if (fx.start && fx.end) {
            var sarr = new Array(), earr = new Array(), spos = fx.start.length, epos = fx.end.length,
                emOffset = fx.start[ss + 1] == 'em' ? (parseInt($(fx.elem).css('fontSize')) * 1.333 * parseInt(fx.start[ss])) : 1;
            for (var ss = 1; ss < spos; ss += 2) { sarr.push(parseInt(emOffset * fx.start[ss])); }
            for (var es = 1; es < epos; es += 2) { earr.push(parseInt(emOffset * fx.end[es])); }
            fx.elem.style.clip = 'rect(' +
                parseInt((fx.pos * (earr[0] - sarr[0])) + sarr[0]) + 'px ' +
                parseInt((fx.pos * (earr[1] - sarr[1])) + sarr[1]) + 'px ' +
                parseInt((fx.pos * (earr[2] - sarr[2])) + sarr[2]) + 'px ' +
                parseInt((fx.pos * (earr[3] - sarr[3])) + sarr[3]) + 'px)';
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

@Shivan Raptor

To control duration, add ***duration: 3000,*** before the step attribute.  So, the code would state:

```
$('#A').on('click', function() {

    $(".img1").animate({
      fontSize: 1
    },
    {
      duration:3000,
      step: function(now, fx) {
          $(this).css('clip', 'rect(0px, '+(now+30)+'px, '+(now+30)+'px, 0px)')
      }
    }, 1000);


});
```

You have to play around with exactly how you want the animation to run, but this should help.