# Touch enabled before/after effect in javascript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, zepto

I'm looking for a Javascript touch enabled before/after filtre that works like this one : http://sfx.thelazy.net/games/screenshot/2298/

The idea is that I want to use exactly the code used in this page, but with "touchmove" events, that does not exist in JQuery as far as I know.

We already tried zepto.flickable.js by tomlongo but that does not work on Android...

Comment: Hammer.js?  https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Compatibility

Comment: I'm just a beginner in javascript but I'll try to deal with it.
Any other link that could do a more close thing to what I want to achieve ?

Comment: Are you talking about how the image differences are shown as you slide over it?  That's easy to do with clip.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847040/animate-the-clip-rect-property