# How to do line animation using CSS and SVG

Tags: javascript, css, svg

My goal is to create scrolling lines similar to [this site](https://www.beepi.com/topfivequestions/). I have started using a simple SVG shape to try and get it to work. I can do a simple animation, but not sure how to fill a specific color from start to finish.

**My SVG:**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="75px" height="100px" viewBox="0 -450 1230 1640" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<path class="path" d="M131.2,-318.8a672.4,672.4,0,0,1,0,1344.8" stroke="black" id="e7_circleArc" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 3px; vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke; stroke-dasharray: 5px, 5px;" />
```

**My CSS**

```
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 500;
  stroke-dashoffset: 5000;
  animation: dash 2s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

You can see the working fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/cbd9L2L3/

Comment: You mean like stroke: blue; or something else?

Comment: The method that website is using is interesting. Can you employ the same method or are you set on SVG? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847040/animate-the-clip-rect-property

Comment: You need to add an event handler to the onscroll event and then trigger the animation when you decide the SVG is on screen "enough".

Comment: @damo-s hey thanks for that link. i did notice they were using the `clip` method but i was unable to replicate that. i'm not set on using svg. think you would be able to help?

Comment: I could give it a shot but just a note that it won't work on lines that loop back on themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the same method as the link you posted - animating the 'bottom' value of `clip: rect()` with jquery. With the difference that I went and used SVG shapes (one for the background and one for the one to be animated) Just a note that `clip` is apparently deprecated and has been replaced with `clip-path`. I tried with `clip-path` but couldn't achieve the same result.

Absolutely position both lines on top of one another if it's not obvious:

```js
$('#line1-overlay').animate({
    fontSize: 515 //some unimportant CSS to animate so we get some values - and height of the line
}, {
    duration: 2000,
    step: function (now, fx) { //now is the animated value from initial css value
      $(this).css('clip', 'rect(0px, 217px, ' + now + 'px, 0px)')
    }
});
```

```css
.line-container {
  position: relative;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="line-container">

  <svg version="1.1" class="line" id="line1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="217px" height="515px" viewBox="0 0 217 515" enable-background="new 0 0 217 515" xml:space="preserve">
  <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M77.229,10.222c64,22,142,140,129,203
    c-13,63-152,60-186,118c-34,58,61,159,130,177"/>
  </svg>

  <svg version="1.1" class="line" id="line1-overlay" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="217px" height="515px" viewBox="0 0 217 515" enable-background="new 0 0 217 515" xml:space="preserve">
  <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M77.229,10.222c64,22,142,140,129,203
    c-13,63-152,60-186,118c-34,58,61,159,130,177"/>
  </svg>

</div>
```

Also: **[JSFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/u0ht2Lyz/)**

Thanks partly to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11847505/1450634).